# SSRS MDX query doesn't work with muti-value parameter

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, mdx

I need your your help!!

I want to create a report with multi-value parameters with SSRS.

So, I wrote this mdx script:

```
WITH 
-- Geography metadata

MEMBER [Measures].[Geographie]
   AS StrToValue ( @SelectionGeographie + ".Hierarchy.Currentmember.Uniquename" )
MEMBER [Measures].[Geographie_Label]
   AS StrToValue( @SelectionGeographie + ".Hierarchy.CurrentMember.Member_Caption" )

-- Activity metadata

MEMBER [Measures].[Activite]
   AS StrToValue( @SelectionActivite + ".Hierarchy.Currentmember.Uniquename" )
MEMBER [Measures].[Activite_Label]
   AS StrToValue( @SelectionActivite + ".Hierarchy.CurrentMember.Member_Caption" )

-- Date metadata

MEMBER [Measures].[Temps]
   AS StrToValue( @Annee + ".Hierarchy.Currentmember.Uniquename" )
MEMBER [Measures].[Temps_Label]
   AS StrToValue( @Annee + ".Hierarchy.CurrentMember.Member_Caption" )

-- Perimetre metadata
MEMBER [Measures].[Perimetre]
   AS StrToValue( @Perimetre + ".Hierarchy.Currentmember.Uniquename" )
MEMBER [Measures].[Perimetre_Label]
   AS StrToValue( @Perimetre + ".Hierarchy.CurrentMember.Member_Caption" )


SELECT NON EMPTY {
 -- display the parameters  attributes on columns

 [Measures].[Geographie],
 [Measures].[Geographie_Label],


 [Measures].[Activite],
 [Measures].[Activite_Label],

 [Measures].[Temps],
 [Measures].[Temps_Label],

 [Measures].[Perimetre],
 [Measures].[Perimetre_Label],


 [Measures].[11 VA]


} ON COLUMNS, 

      ( STRTOSET ( "{" + @SelectionGeographie + "}") ,


        STRTOSET   ("{" + @SelectionActivite + "}" ))


ON ROWS

FROM [MyCube]

WHERE STRTOTUPLE ( "(" +@Annee + "," + @Perimetre + ")" )
```

But It works with one value in parameter and not with muti-value parameters.
 I have null result in my metadata members when I have multi value.

Any idea ?

Thank U

Comment: Noone ? I don't know why That works when I have only one parameter and not with many parameters ? is it possible to use the uniquename functions with muti-value ?

Comment: With Reporting Services multiple parameters is nicely working for us, so the problem is somehow elsewhere -> 'Hierarchy.' this looks strange to me

Comment: Hi IcCube, Thank U for your answer. I replaced hierarchy.CurrentMember by CurrentMember and it's the same. No result for the multivalue parameter. i think the StrToValue function doesn't like the multivalue. But When I delete it like this I have now an error

Comment: It's difficult from here to  help you, try a version just showing the parameters, something is wrong there in the way you build them -> WITH MEMBER param1 as @NiveauGeographie ... select {param1, ...} on 0 from [YourCube]..

Comment: Thank U IcCube. I' ll try it and i will come back.

Answer (score 1):

> WITH 
>   -- Geography metadata 
>     MEMBER [Measures].[Geographie] AS  "[Geographie]."+        @NiveauGeographie +".Currentmember.Uniquename"
>
> MEMBER [Measures].[Geographie_Label] AS  "[Geographie]."+ @NiveauGeographie
>   +".CurrentMember.Member_Caption"
>
> SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Geographie],
>   [Measures].[Geographie_Label], [Measures].[11 VA]
>
> } ON COLUMNS,
>
> ( STRTOSET ( "{" + @SelectionGeographie + "}") ,
>
> ```
> STRTOSET   ("{" + @SelectionActivite + "}" ))
> ```
>
> ON ROWS
>
> FROM [MyCube]
>
> WHERE STRTOTUPLE ( "(" +@Annee + "," + @Perimetre + ")"